Configuring npm to access private GitHub repo with token: HTTPS Setup Not Working
I am facing an issue with installing a private GitHub repository into another private repository using GitHub Actions and npm. The private repository is not published to npm but is hosted on GitHub. I have added token in repo where I am installing as TOKEN.
I encountered errors related to Git SSH authentication and repository access during npm install, with error code 128. The errors indicated permission issues with SSH access and repository not found errors.
To resolve this I attempted to configure Git to use HTTPS instead of SSH for accessing the repository. This involved setting up Git configuration with a token. Used the following configuration in the GitHub Actions workflow:
git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

I tested cloning the repository directly using the token to ensure that the token configuration was correct. This worked when using the token directly in the git clone command.
Despite configuring Git to use HTTPS and adding the token, npm install still attempted to use SSH
git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

and failed with similar errors:
    npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
    npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/org/repo.git
    npm ERR! fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/repo/' not found

As a workaround I added configuration to .npmrc to handle private npm packages, which includes:
echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
echo "@your-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/" >> ~/.npmrc

Although this resolves the SSH permission issue, npm install still fails with errors related to the repository not being found. The repository URL in the error messages indicates that npm is still attempting to use the SSH protocol despite the HTTPS configuration.
How can I ensure that npm install correctly uses the HTTPS URL with the provided token for accessing a private GitHub repository?
Here is the workflow file
name: Run test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # Fetch all history to ensure all dependencies are included

      - name: Test Git Clone
        run: |
          git clone https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/repo.git

      - name: Set up .npmrc for private repo
        run: |
          echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
          echo "@your-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/" >> ~/.npmrc

      - name: Set up Git to use HTTPS with Token
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test



Are these private repositories under the same account?

Yes same organisation

It looks like you have configured npm to use GitHub Packages and to use your PAT token to have permissions to access your org npm packages published to GitHub Packages. I removed the trailing slash:
      echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
      echo "@your-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> ~/.npmrc

All that is left now is to correctly configure the packages you want to install in package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@your-org/my-package": "1.0.0"
  }
}

I am not sure why you need to checkout the other repo:
  - name: Test Git Clone
    run: |
      git clone https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/repo.git

and why you need this step:
  - name: Set up Git to use HTTPS with Token
    run: |
      git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

